# PostgreSQL: Generate custom MongoDB-ObjectID-like UUID's as primary key

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, uuid, objectid

I've been reading a lot about implementing UUID's in postgres because I need to be able to generate my ID's in some cases before they are sent to the database.  A lot of the reading I've done warns about the impact UUID's have on performance.  They mention how a non-sequential primary key would drastically bog down the performance.

The UUID v4 is useless since using all random numbers to calculate the id is non-sequential since it's random.  I want to use v1, but including the MAC address in the id seems unnecessary and not secure.  What I want to be able to do is generate a MongoDB ObjectID-style UUID.  I want it to basically be composed of the timestamp and table name so that when the ID's are sorted, it is sorted in sequential order.

Is there a way to do there where I can generate this custom UUID and have Postgres store them in a sequential fashion based on the timestamp on the uuid?

Comment: *They mention how a non-sequential primary key would drastically bog down the performance.*. What? Huh? Citations please. URLs, article names, etc. The main issue with UUID is that it's 128 bytes wide so your indexes are bigger and slower to query.

Comment: Oh, you plan to use a uuid instead of a timestamp, or rely on the timestamp embedded in a v1 uuid. Don't do that. Store a timestamp as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:
Create ObjectIds in PostGres following the MongoDB semantics. Very similar to the Instagram approach linked below. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram
https://gist.github.com/jamarparris/6100413